# Is there a way around the three letters of recommendation?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I had lackluster grades before I dropped out of high scbool and acquired my GED in 2005. It seems like every college I'm interested in requires two letters of recommendation (Cal Arts requires 3) and I'm not sure how to get them. 
I could enroll in a community college, but the credits don't tranfer, and I'm not sure I see the merit in attending. I did pretty well on the ACT, and did some pretty interesting work on my portfolio, but I have no one to write meaninful letters.

My only employment has been the 12 years of service I put in at my parents store. I doubt my mothers letter would carry much weight, and two of my favorite teachers have passed away. I have some successful friends, but I don't really see how that would be relevant. The schools want three letters from the teachers that know me best, and I have nothing.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE! Unfortunately, questions about undergraduate admissions are generally [not on-topic for this site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: You're answering your own question. the merit in going to community college is getting recommendation letters.

Comment: Echoing @Johanna, before this gets closed: community college coursework will get you those letters... and, no, there's no way around them. It's not an issue of transferring credits.

Comment: If you're applying to Cal Arts, you must have had an art or music teacher?

Comment: I wish you the best of luck with your application David. Although 12 years of service at your parent's store really doesn't count for much, I think its clear that you really want to go to college, despite your situation, age, previous grades, etc etc. If I were you, i'd call up those colleges and say "I've got from now 'till X to make my application great - what can I do between then that gives me the best possible chance at your college?"

Comment: Hold on there, user33 -- 12 years of service at parents' store counts for quite a bit in terms of character and work ethic.